# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I implemented a search by attribute in Openlayers, here is the part of the code:

```
$(document).on('change','#forminput',function(){
        var desiredvalue = this.value;
        alert('change'+desiredvalue);
        $(document).on('click','#mybutton',function(){
            alert('clicked' +desiredvalue)
            myFeature = layer_agao.getFeaturesByAttribute('clandpin',desiredvalue)[0];
            selectControl.clickFeature(myFeature);
        });
});
```

The `clandpins` were AJAX loaded value.

```
<select name="forminput" class="form-control" id="forminput" style="width: 200px">
    <option type="text">Select Land PIN</option>              
</select>
```

The option values is appended using AJAX.

Comment: `$('#forminput').on('change',function()` is wrong. You missed second part (ie) `$('#forminput').on('change',selector,function()`

Comment: It still returns the same error.It can't get the layer although I declared it globally.

Comment: Same.`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer' of undefined`

Comment: can you post your updated `$('#forminput').on('change'` again? try moveing the `$(document).on('click','#mybutton',function()` outside

Comment: I edited the code...the value from `#forminput` were AJAX loaded. It is a select option HTML.

Comment: what is `#forminput`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the feature that you are trying to search does not exists. I just messed up with the queries.